# How do I turn 67 into float equivalent?

Tags: c#, floating-point, type-conversion

I'm using a library where I need to set a value on a variable and it only accepts `float` type, but the `TrackBar` Control only accepts `Int32` for its `Value` property.

So let's say that the Min value of `TrackBar` is 0 and Max value is 100. And the Current value of `TrackBar` is 67; how do I convert that value to its equivalent in float? So it should become something *like* 0.067, if I'm correct.

Comment: `.67` is probably what you want. `.067` means 67 thousandths not 67 hundredths.

Comment: @Hogan If you're declaring the float, you should have it `=0.67f`. See [Why is the “f” required when declaring floats?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11519743/why-is-the-f-required-when-declaring-floats)

Comment: @Okuma.Scott - no idea what you are talking about, I'm not declaring anything -- I'm just pointing out what `.067` and `.67` mean.

Comment: @Hogan Okay, it wasn't clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To convert `int` to float just cast:

```
(float)trackBar.Value;
```

or

```
Convert.ToSingle(trackBar.Value);
```

Note that if you need to change range you need to perform at least division. I.e. in your case it looks like value is percentage, so divide by 100.0:

```
trackBar.Value / 100.0f;
```

Note that if you use `100` than result will be wrong as using integer division ( `trackBar.Value / 100` will always be `0`).

In general conversion for integer in `0-n` range to `(mixValue, maxValue)` range:

```
 (trackBar.Value /( (float) maxValue - minValue)) + minValue;
```

Comment: Neither of those work. The minimum value of this float variable is 0 and maximum is 1. I need to get all numbers inbetween 0 and 1. (i.e.: 0.01, 0.02, 0.03, 0.04, 0.05, 0.06, 0.07, 0.08, 0.09, 1) but with both your examples, the result is always the same: 1.

Comment: @JasonPezzimenti, can you edit your post to add this information, along with a quick code example? Highlight what each of the data types are.

Comment: Then just divide by 100!    Convert.ToSingle(trackBar.Value) / 100.0;

Comment: -1: please make sure to edit in comments to provide complete answer. Thanks you.

Comment: @Mangist - I've edited your post with percentage/range comments to show what I thing would be ok answer. Feel free to rollback and put your own version.

Answer (score 2):

Divide the integer value by 100 as a `float` to get the percentage as a `float`. This will cause the value to be normalized to fall between 0 and 1 as a decimal value:

```
float trackBarPercentage = trackBar.Value / 100f;
```

Dividing the `integer` value by a `float` value will cause the right-hand side to automatically be casted to the `float` type. See the MSDN article [Casting and Type Conversions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173105.aspx) for more info.