# floats being saved as 0 after calculation

Tags: c#

Very confused here, I have this code:

```
float temp = (1/10)*100;
Label.Text = Convert.ToString(temp);
```

for some reason my temp variable is being saved as 0 which means my label text is changed to 0 when I'm expecting 10, I have the same issue when using doubles instead. What has gone wrong?

Comment: `float temp = (1/10.0)*100`; 1/10 integer division -> == 0 * 100 == 0

Comment: its being converted to integer somewhere

Comment: Please read this- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11519743/why-is-the-f-required-when-declaring-floats. By the way you have done zero efforts to search for it.

Comment: Yep, problem is `1/10` is two integers being divided. Simple fix is `1.0f / 10.0f` which explicitly declares both numbers as floats so there's no surprises.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since 1, 10 and 100 are all integer values, the division is also an int value, rounded down. In this case `1/10 = 0` so `(1/10)*100 = 0`
If you do not want this try using floats:

`(1.0f/10)*100`

In case you're working with integer variables you have to convert them first. This can be achieved by casting, like so:

```
int a=1;
...
float b = ((float) a)/10; // b will be 0.1
```

Another quick way of doing this in a line with multiple operations is multiplying by 1.0f:

```
int x = 100;
float c = (a*1.0f)/x;  // c will be 0.01f
```

Comment: If I was using variables instead of just the numeric values I'm assuming I'd just need to convert them all to floats first?

Comment: @AndrewNeate yes, I updated the answer