# Why we don't need suffix after conversion but during declaration we need it?

Tags: c#, type-conversion

Float is not accepting suffix f when converting from string to float using C#. I want to convert string to float & my string already has "F" suffix within it. but the float is not accepting suffix f when converting from string to float & throws an exception.

```
static void Main()
{
    string any_str = "123.45F";
    float f = float.Parse(any_str);       
    Console.WriteLine(f);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using a lowercase f instead of an uppercase one?

Comment: Yes ...it's not working with a lower case as well.

Comment: You could try to replace the f from the string before parsing it to the float value. Using the string.Replace method

Comment: Why do you find that amazing? The 'f'/'F' etc.. are only for code, neither for input nor for output.

Comment: I can do that but I want to know why it will not work after conversion ?

Comment: Why we don´t need suffix after conversion but during declaretion we need it?

Comment: One is for coders&compilers one for normal people! You wouldn't want to show it to your customers, right? So why accept it as input??

Answer (score 4):

Basically `float.Parse` can't do anything with that f suffix.  `float.Parse` will just take a string representing a numerical value, any extra nonnumerical characters will throw an exception.  The f suffix is just for use, by you, in your code itself.  So as [fahime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56512223/why-we-don%C2%B4t-need-suffix-after-conversion-but-during-declaretion-we-need-it/56512268#56512268) and [Norse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56512223/why-we-don%C2%B4t-need-suffix-after-conversion-but-during-declaretion-we-need-it/56512313#56512313) said you'll need to get rid of that 'f' before using `float.Parse`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think `float.Parse` has any build in functionality for this, but you could create an extension method for your own convenience.

```
public static float ToFloat(this string value)
{
    return float.Parse(value.TrimEnd('f', 'F'));
}
```

Use as such:

```
any_str.ToFloat();
```

EDIT: Some may suggest you use `Regex` to clear out any letters or symbols, but it is not very performant; only use it when you know you will have symbols other than the `f` or `F` at the end.

Answer (score 1):

> Why we don´t need suffix after conversion but during declaration we
>   need it?

By default and by C# specifications every number has a `floating point` will consider as a `Double` variable so you need to use an `F` suffix to create a literal for this type.

```
// 3.14 is considered a double variable by the compiler so it gives you an error
float myFloat = 3.14;
```

You might ask why a double variable with value `3.14` cannot be assigned or cast into a float variable?

http://net-informations.com/q/faq/float.html

> The Decimal, Double, and Float variable types are different in the way
>   that they store the values. Precision is the main difference where
>   float is a single precision (32 bit) floating point data type, double
>   is a double precision (64 bit) floating point data type and decimal is
>   a 128-bit floating point data type.
>
> Float - 32 bit (7 digits) Double - 64 bit (15-16 digits)
>   The main difference is Floats and Doubles are binary floating point
>   types and a Decimal will store the value as a floating decimal point
>   type. So Decimals have much higher precision and are usually used
>   within monetary (financial) applications that require a high degree of
>   accuracy. But in performance wise Decimals are slower than double and
>   float types.

[You can read this answer as well.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11590321/553825)

And about `Parse` method:

`float.Parse` only requires a valid string which means only a string includes [`0-9`], sign character and the decimal point ( vary by culture for eg [`,/.`]).

So you only need to get rid of any non-valid chars from your strings then parse it.

Comment: You suggested using regex while you downvoted my answer because of the same solution!!

Comment: @fahime I don't give him a solution, He already knows that he can remove the `f` at the end of it, he just wants to know why `f` is required during the declaration and etc ...

Answer (score -1):

You need to remove all alphabetical chars in your input:

```
public static void Main()
{
    string any_str = "123.45F";
    string numberOnly = Regex.Replace(any_str, "[^0-9.]", "");
    float f = float.Parse(numberOnly);       
    Console.WriteLine(f);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: He wants to see if `Parse` could parse it or not.

Comment: He wants to convert a string to float and faced an exception! So it could be the solution.

Comment: This code with neither work for valid strings like `-1`, `1.23E+10`, `NaN`, `Infinity` nor for certain locales which use other characters than a period as a separator (e.g. in German it‘s 123,45). Instead of a whitelist approach, a blacklist approach like the one proposed by @Norse is better.