# Is there a reason to always declare floats with the type suffix 'f' in C#?

Tags: c#, floating-point, literals, suffix

When creating float variables, integers don't *need* a type suffix, i.e. all of these are valid:

```
public float distance = 3;
public float distance = 3f;
public float distance = 0.3f;
```

Is there a reason to use `3f` instead of `3`? Is the compiler smart enough to recognize the type as float and automatically cast it?

Related Questions:
[Why Should we use literals in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/732770/why-should-we-use-literals-in-c?lq=1) and [Why is the "f" required when declaring floats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11519743/why-is-the-f-required-when-declaring-floats?lq=1)

Both explain *why* we need to use the type suffix 'f', but is there a 'correct' way to declare floats that have integer values? Is one way more efficient?

Comment: Really good answer on this page have a look : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11519743/why-is-the-f-required-when-declaring-floats

Comment: @UmairNisarBajwaOMAIR I already have that question linked in my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the list of allowed [Implicit Numeric Conversions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y5b434w4.aspx).  Implicit conversions are allowed when the target *type* can hold the original *type* range.  In the case, `float distance = 0.3;` is an error because a float range cannot accommodate the double range.

As to efficiency, between `3` and `3f`, the compiler should optimize for you.

```
IL_0001:  ldc.r4     3.   // float distance1 = 3;
IL_0006:  stloc.0
IL_0007:  ldc.r4     3.   // float distance2 = 3f;
IL_000c:  stloc.1
```

Comment: Oh now that's interesting and kind of what I was interested in knowing, was after it's compiled, does it make a real difference or are they the same, and it looks here that the compiler is smart enough to make them the same, so ultimately it's preference and readability. Thanks!

Comment: FYI, you can use the [Ildasm.exe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7dy01k1(v=vs.110).aspx) tool to view the IL.

Answer (score 1):

The need for the `f` suffix becomes obvious in your 3rd example:

```
public float distance = 0.3f;
```

If you remove the `f`, the `0.3` will be interpreted as a `double` and will generate a compilation error, because a `double` can't be downcast implicitly and assigned to a `float` variable.  You need to specify that `0.3` is a float literal in that case.

Comment: Correct, but if it is an integer, I don't need to explicitly declare it as a float with `f`, but is there a reason *to* declare it as a float regardless of the value? i.e. should I always add `f` or is it all just preference?

Comment: So say I have a function that accepts three floats `void Position(float x, float y, float z)` and I pass it integers `Position(2,5,18)`, would it be better practice to use the type suffix? `Position(2f,5f,18f)` or is there very little impact?

Comment: I would get in the habit of using the suffix if I really need a `float`, because normally, I would expect that most values will have a decimal portion, in which case, the suffix is required.  If you always find yourself passing integer values, one has to wonder why you are using the `float` data type in the first place.

Comment: Makes sense, the only other case is: `distance *= 2f;`, where I still need the type to be float, but I am multiplying by a constant integer. Either way makes little difference, but was just curious if there was an 'unwritten rule' about using type suffixes.

Answer (score 1):

Pragmatics. The f is not required. However, note that a decimal point number without the "f" suffix is interpreted as a double, a more precise but memory-expensive primitive. Consider the following:

```
public float distance = 3.123456789123456;
```

The right-hand of this assignment is interpreted first, and without the "f" connotation, it is perceived as a double. Compiler error would occur here. Because floats are less precise (holding 7 decimal places vs a double's 15), you would lose accuracy, and the variable "distance" would now be something more somewhere around 3.123457.

Comment: Ok so it really it's just preference as to whether you should add the `f` with integers or not? And to expand on your point about precision, if you were add the f `public float distance = 3.123456789123456f;` then print that out distance, the result would be `3.123456` due to the accuracy of the float type.

Comment: Xander-

Correct. What it really comes down to in regards to integers is convenience for yourself and other developers working with you later on. When you have a complex project with multiple variables, sometimes it's just nice to see:
    public float distance = 3.0f; 
instead of
    public float distance = 3; 

And yes, 
    public float distance = 3.123456789123456f; 
would only keep track of 7 decimal places.

Answer (score 0):

If you write `float dist = 3;` it can be without `f`. But in you assign `object dist = 3f;` then you need `f` because otherwise it will be defined as integer.

Comment: Also: There are some method overloads in the framwork that depend on a  float param being written explicitly.

Comment: just a sidenote because I saw your edit, the type suffix can be either upper or lowercase.